# The $\sigma$-algebra generated by all projections is not contained in the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the first $n$ projections

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

> Let $B = \{a,b \}$ be a set with two elements and let $X = B^\mathbb{N}$ be the set of all sequences with elements in $B$.
>
> For every positive integer $n$, let $\pi_n: X \to B$ be the projection on the $n$-th component, i.e. $\pi_n((x_i)_{i})=  x_n$ for every $(x_i)_i \in X$.
>
> Let $\mathcal{A} \subset \mathcal{P}(X)$ be the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the functions $\pi_i$ for every positive integer $i$, and for every positive integer $n$, let $\mathcal{A}_n \subset \mathcal{P}(B^n)$ be the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the functions $\pi_1, \pi_2, \cdots, \pi_n$.
>
> What is an example of a set $A \in \mathcal{A}$ that is not contained in any $\mathcal{A}_n$?

In other words, by the above definition, $\{\mathcal{A}_n \}_{n}$ is a filtration. So we need to find an example of a set that is $\mathcal{A}$-measurable, but it is not measurable in any set from the filtration. I really don't know how to begin constructing such example.

We can also say that $\mathcal{A}_n$ is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $p_n$, where $p_n$ is the projection on the first $n$ components, i.e. $$p_n : X \to B^n, p_n((x_i)_{i}) = (x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_n), $$ which makes it easier to work with every $\mathcal{A}_n$, but it is still difficult to work with $\mathcal{A}$.

A somewhat similar question is this one: [Is the product measure space generated by the filtration adapted to the projection maps?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1118033/is-the-product-measure-space-generated-by-the-filtration-adapted-to-the-projecti/1118236), however, the $\sigma$-algebra is different than the one here.

I can see that the intuition behind this is that the elements from $\mathcal{A}_n$ for each $n$ are those that can "be known in finite time", but I still don't know how to begin constructing an example. Any help would be really appreciated.

Would the set $$U = \{(x_{1,i})_i, (x_{2,i})_i, (x_{3,i})_i, \cdots \}$$ such that $\displaystyle x_{n,i} = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll} a, \text{ if } i \leq n \\ b, \text{ otherwise } \end{array} \right.$ help in any way?

Comment: Do you understand what the question is asking for? That is, is there any specific part of the question itself you don't understand?

Comment: I understand the question, but I don't know how to begin constructing such an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a good point to start with is reading up on [tail-sigma-algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1047306/events-in-the-tail-sigma-algebra) again. Then it is actually not that hard, it coincides with your intuition of "can be known in finite time".

Now, if you want a concrete example solution, see below.

Set $A:=  \bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} \bigcap \limits_{k=i}^{\infty} [\pi_{k}=a] $ (aka $[ \lim_{n -> \infty} x_n = a]$ ) Clearly,
$ [\pi_{k} = a] \in \mathcal{A}_{k} \subset \mathcal A, k \in \mathbb N$ , but $[\pi_{k+1} =a] \notin A_{k}$. $A \in \mathscr A$ follows directly from the property of a $ \sigma$-algebra.

Comment: What is the set $[\pi_k = a]$? Is it the pre-image under $\pi_k$ of the set of all sequences which have limit $a$?

Comment: Sorry if that notation was unlcear, it is "short" for $\pi_k^{-1} (\{a\})$ - i.e. for a fixed k, this is just all the sequences which have $x_k = a$

Comment: Thank you! Now I understand your answer.

Comment: I can see why $A \in \mathcal{A}$, but why do we have that $A \notin A_k, \forall k$?

Comment: This was (maybe a bit sloppy) implied in $[\pi_{k+1} = a] \notin A_{k}$, since the particular $A_{k}$ are of the form $A_{k} = \{S \subset B^{\mathbb N} | S = \{ (x_{i})_{i \in \mathbb N} | x_{j} = c_{j}, with \ c_{j} \in \{a,b\}, j \in J \subset \{1,...k\}\}\}$ - So, any element of $A_{k}$ will contain some sequences that are in $\mathcal A$, and others, that are not (the information about these terminal events is in none of the "finite" sub-sigma-algebras)

Comment: I think you are referring to $A_k$ as $\mathcal{A}_k$ (OP's notations). I don't see why $\mathcal{A}_k$ is of the form that you have written, since $\mathcal{A}_k$ is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the first $k$ projections. Also, you are saying that $[\pi_k = a] \in A_k \subset A$;  are you referring here to $A$ as $\mathcal{A}$?  Again, I still don't see why the fact that $[\pi_{k+1} = a] \notin A_k$ implies that $A \notin A_k$. How would you prove this? Since $[\pi_{k+1} = a] \notin A_k,$ then $\bigcap_{t=k+i}^\infty [\pi_t = a] \notin A_k$ for any $k$ or $i$. Does this imply the result?

Comment: You're right about the notation, edited that. I'm not sure right now whether in a general case (i.e. arbitraty $B$) the argument that $[\pi_{k+1} =a] \notin \mathcal {A}_{k}$ would lead to $A \notin \mathcal {A}_{k}$, but in this specific case it is the right intuition. A formal proof for the whole thing would be : 1.) Define $ \mathcal A_{k}$ as in my last comment 2.) Show that for a fixed k, every set $ \pi_{j}^{-1}(S), j \in \{1...k\}, S \subset \mathcal P(B)$ is in  $\mathcal A_{k}$.   3.) Show that $\mathcal A_{k}$ as defined above is indeed a $\sigma$-Algebra.

Comment: 4.) Conclude that $\mathcal A_{k}$ is indeed the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $(\pi_{1},...\pi_{k})$. 5.) Pick any set $S$ in $\mathcal A_{k}$, which will be as of the form above, i.e. there will be some requirements for some of the first k elements of any sequence in that set, but not for the k+1-th element and so on. 6.) Now in that set $S$ you can easily find a sequence $(x_{n})_{n \in\mathbb N}$, which is in $A$ (our set defined initially). - You can actually pick any sequence that is in there and set $x_{i}:= a, i \in {k+1,....\infty}$, and the resulting sequence will still be in $S$

Comment: 7.) On the other hand, you can also find a sequence in $S$ which is not in $A$, by setting every entry after k to $b$. As $S$ was arbitrary, you have shown that for any Set $S \in \mathcal A_{k}$, $S \neq A$, hence $ \implies A \notin \mathcal A_{k}$